# What script do I have to use to run A/B test instead of split URL in Google optimize?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, ab-testing, google-optimize, abtest

I have a different page that Is ready and I want to start an A/B test in Google optimize instead of Split url because Split URL loading time sucks in Google Optimize. Is there a script for A/B test that will work as Split URL (automatically change the content on the page)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.  I have used the "Redirect AB Test" in Optimize 360, but there's no other option, other than to run AB Tests, MVTs or Personalisation.

Why not use the AB Testing feature?